# ES6 generator functions in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ecmascript-6, angular-promise

recently I started using generators in my angular project. Here's how I do it so far:

```
function loadPosts(skip) {
    return $rootScope.spawn(function *() {
        try {
            let promise = yield User.findAll();
            $timeout(function () {
                // handle the user list
            });
        } catch (err) {
            // handle err
        }
    });
}
```

From what I've read the next part won't be necessary in es7, but currently I have the `spawn` function in the run block of my app.

```
$rootScope.spawn = function (generatorFunc) {
    function continuer(verb, arg) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = generator[verb](arg);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }
        if (result.done) {
            return result.value;
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        }
    }
    var generator = generatorFunc();
    var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, "next");
    var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, "throw");
    return onFulfilled();
};
```

Everything works find the way I do it at the moment, the only thing I really don't like is that I have to call `$timeout()` after each promise. If I don't my `$scope` variables initialized inside the timeout won't be initialized. It seems to me that angular digest system needs to be triggered manually.

Why is that and is there a way to make this cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume it is because your `spawn` method uses native `Promise`s, not the angular implementation. Try to use [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead:

```
function continuer(verb, arg) {
    var result;
    try {
        result = generator[verb](arg);
    } catch (err) {
        return $q.reject(err);
    }
    if (result.done) {
        return result.value;
    } else {
        return $q.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
    }
}
```